# Запрос на удаление(или связывание) метки [windows-form-application]

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки

Есть метка [windows-form-application](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-form-application) её надо либо удалить, либо же связать с [winforms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms)